# Search a range in parse javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a Class that help me to keep a range of values, it consist in 3 columns named min, max and price. When the user give me a number (example quantity=5) I need to search all the prices that the quantity satisfy this rule: 
quantity=5  min >= quantity AND max <= quantity

```
var quantity = Number(req.body.quantity);
var Range   = Parse.Object.extend("PriceRange");
var query = new Parse.Query(Range);
query.limit(1000);
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("min",quantity);
query.lessThanOrEqualTo("max",quantity);
```

When I make this the result is always 0 and I have a row that is min = 1, max = 10 and price = 10

What is wrong? Parse don´t let me do querys like that?

Comment: Hi, I suggest rephrase the question and add missing objects and variables.

Comment: I hope that now its more easy to understand

Comment: Please share more code and details: What is the code of Parse? Or is it a Library? How do you extract the result from query? what greaterThanOrEqualTo and lessThanOrEqualTo accepts as parameters?

Share link to the documentations of the libraries you are using

Comment: It appears you've received several answers on the site without ever marking one correct.  Doing so -- when one has helped you -- is appropriate and will get you better help on the  next question.

Comment: @chenop - the question is tagged parse.com, so the OP is not obligated to (and should not) explain all about parse.com in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the inequalities are reversed.

```
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("min",quantity);  // means: min >= quantity
query.lessThanOrEqualTo("max",quantity);     // means: max <= quantity
```

...constrains the query to find objects *where the value of min is greater than quantity*, and likewise for the other constraint.

Those two constraints together present an impossible condition: where some number is both smaller than some small number and larger than some large number.  Fix by reversing...

```
query.lessThanOrEqualTo("min",quantity);     // where min <= quantity
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("max",quantity);  // where max >= quantity
```